# How to remove ID in URL in Laravel return

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Laravel 5.4, Everything works fine but one thing is bugging me,
When I edit my Data and submit and use  `return view('role.index');`
The URL returns this :`8000/role/1`, it returns a extra ID which is I don't know where it came from here is my code:-

```
public function edit(Role $role)
{
    return view('role.edit')->with('details', $role);
}


public function update(Request $request, Role $role)
{
    $user=auth()->user();
    $role->role=$request->get('role');;

    $role->updated_by=$user->id;

    $role->save();
    return view('role.index');

}
```

Comment: You can use redirect to a route which calls a function returning view `role.index`

Comment: @SagarGautam Thank you its works like magic !!!

Comment: Glad to see, Congrats :)

Answer (score -1):

i understood it wrong but the reason that it happens because the route of the update is a "PUT request with the id" -> http://yourwebsite/role/1
you are returning a view inside this route you are still in the Role controller and update method.
***The solution***
instead of returning a view just

```
return back();
```

at the last of the update method